# Stern-Brocot Tree with Python

Tags: python

My goal is to output the Stern-Brocot result for any given n. I have a rough sensing of how the code should work, but I do not know how to simplify the code to work with any n values. The code below is up till when n=2.

```py
def stern_brocot(n):
    L = [(0,1),(1,1)]
    if n == 0:
        return L
    else:
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            if i == 1:
                a = L[i-1][i-1] + L[i][i-1]
                b = L[i-1][i] + L[i][i]
                L.insert(i,(a,b))
            if i == 2:
                a = L[i-2][i-2] + L[i-1][i-2]
                b = L[i-2][i-1] + L[i-1][i-1]
                L.insert(i-1,(a,b))
                c = L[i][i-2]+L[i+1][i-2]
                d = L[i][i-1]+L[i+1][i-1]
                L.insert(i+1,(c,d))
        return L
```

results:

`stern_brocot(0)` =>    `[(0, 1), (1, 1)]`

`stern_brocot(1)` =>    `[(0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 1)]`

`stern_brocot(2)` =>    `[(0, 1), (1, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 1)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion:

```
def sb_tree(rn, n):
   if not n:
      return rn
   def new_rn():
      for i in range(len(rn) - 1):
         yield from (rn[i], tuple(map(sum, zip(rn[i], rn[i+1]))))
      yield rn[i+1]
   return sb_tree(list(new_rn()), n-1)

for i in range(5):
   print(list(sb_tree([(0,1), (1,0)], i)))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 0)]
[(0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)]
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 1), (2, 1), (1, 0)]
[(0, 1), (1, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 1), (3, 2), (2, 1), (3, 1), (1, 0)]
[(0, 1), (1, 4), (1, 3), (2, 5), (1, 2), (3, 5), (2, 3), (3, 4), (1, 1), (4, 3), (3, 2), (5, 3), (2, 1), (5, 2), (3, 1), (4, 1), (1, 0)]
```